# QGIS modelbuilder Error on expression when similar Expressions Run Fine

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I am currently trying to build a algorithm model that does some conversions of a attribute tables. It was working fine in a while I was building things step by step however a new expression does not seem to be working. Even though there are similar expressions that are just working fine. To give some context there is a certain column where the data is structured like this.

{ "diepteNauwkeurigheid": "Onbekend", "dieptePeil": "1 m" }

Because you only have this where in some special cases where the ImklType/header(other columns) is equal to certain values and because my model is pretty complex, I have made some case Expressions on some other columns to extract that data for those specefic situations. For example the dieptePeil(P), diepteNauwkeurigheid(P), P standing for Poles. I have made this:

```
For dieptePeil(P)
CASE when Header = 'Pole' THEN
string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[7]
ELSE
NULL
end

For diepteNauwkeurigheid(P)
    CASE when Header = 'Pole' THEN
    string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[2]
    ELSE
    NULL
    end
```

**But here is the kicker these case expressions run fine no errors what so ever but when I try to run a similar expression things go wrong**

```
For dieptePeil (Ann):

    CASE When Imkltype = 'annotationlabel' THEN
    string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[7]
    ELSE
    NULL
    END

For DiepteNauwkeurigheid(Ann)

CASE When Imkltype = 'annotationlabel' THEN
string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[2]
ELSE
NULL
END
```

These are the two expression when things go wrong or more specifically this dieptePeil (Ann) one, because that is where the error occurs.

```
Fout in evaluatie in expressie "CASE When Imkltype = 'annotationlabel' THEN 
string_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,'"')[7] 
ELSE 
NULL 
END": [] can only be used with map or array values, not 
Fout bij uitvoeren van Omzetting fase 1: Punten
Fout bij uitvoeren van Omzetting fase 1: Punten
Uitvoering mislukt na 0.48 seconden
```

What is going on here?
Here is the complete log:

```
QGIS versie: 3.10.6-A Coruña
QGIS coderevisie: ec80021f49
Qt versie: 5.11.2
GDAL versie: 3.0.4
GEOS versie: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ versie: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Uitvoeren van algoritme…
Algoritme 'KLIP Omzet' starten...
Parameters invoer:
{ 'native:extractbyattribute_10:Ducts' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'native:package_1:Geodatabase Klip' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'pkmlBestand' : 'pmkl.json', 'pmkllines' : 'C:/Users/joeri/Documents/GIS/IKML Mercator/ORDVV2001815 Zelzate (GVV)/pmkl.json|layername=featureCollection|geometrytype=LineString', 'pmklpoints' : 'C:/Users/joeri/Documents/GIS/IKML Mercator/ORDVV2001815 Zelzate (GVV)/pmkl.json|layername=featureCollection|geometrytype=Point', 'pmklpolygons' : 'C:/Users/joeri/Documents/GIS/IKML Mercator/ORDVV2001815 Zelzate (GVV)/pmkl.json|layername=featureCollection|geometrytype=Polygon', 'qgis:refactorfields_10:Map Request Laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_11:Extra Plan Laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_12:Laag Electricity Cable' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_13:Laag SewerPipes' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_14:Laag Waterpipes' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_15:Laag Ducts' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_16:Annotaties lijne' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_2:Conversielijnen' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_4:Al-Pole_Point' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_5:Cabinet Laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_6:Appurtenance laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_7:Laag Annotaties' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_8:Dekking laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'qgis:refactorfields_9:Diepte laag' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

Algoritme voorbereiden: qgis:refactorfields_1
Uitvoeren Omzetting fase 1: Punten [1/28]
Parameters invoer:
{ FIELDS_MAPPING: [{'expression': 'CASE WHEN "elementType" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "elementType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'elementType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when "liggingNauwkeurigheid" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "liggingNauwkeurigheid" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND\r\n', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'liggingNauwkeurigheid', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN currentStatus IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("currentStatus",\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'currentStatus', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"imkltype"', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'imkltype', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"header"', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'header', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"filterType"', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'filterType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "beginLifespanVersion" Is NOT NULL \r\nTHEN\r\nto_datetime(string_to_array("beginLifespanVersion" ,\'"\')[7])\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'beginLifespanVersion', 'precision': 0, 'type': 16}, {'expression': '"extraPlanType"', 'length': 2555555, 'name': 'extraPlanType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "betandMediaType" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("betandMediaType",\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'bestandMediaType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"fileId"', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'fileId', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"isDirectlyLinkedByUna"', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'isDirectlyLinkedByUna', 'precision': 0, 'type': 1}, {'expression': '"fileName"', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'fileName', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"filePackageLocation"', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'filePackageLocation', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "references" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("references" ,\':\')[2]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND\r\n', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'references', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"label"', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'label', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when "poleHeight" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "poleHeight" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'poleHeight', 'precision': 2, 'type': 6}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN standaardDekking IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'standaardDekking', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN omschrijving IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "omschrijving" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'omschrijving', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "validTo" Is NOT NULL \r\nTHEN\r\nto_datetime(string_to_array("validTo" ,\'"\')[7])\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'End Life', 'precision': 0, 'type': 16}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN verticalPosition IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("verticalPosition",\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\n\'missing\'\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'verticalPosition', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when subThema IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "subThema" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'subThema', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN pipeDiameter IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "pipeDiameter" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'pipeDiameter', 'precision': 0, 'type': 4}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN waterType IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "waterType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'waterType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"materiaalType"', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'materiaalType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"TechnicalSpecification"', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'TechnicalSpecification', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"hasSpecificDepth"', 'length': 1, 'name': 'hasSpecificDepth', 'precision': 0, 'type': 1}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN ductWidth IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "ductWidth" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555555, 'name': 'ductWidth', 'precision': 0, 'type': 4}, {'expression': 'Case when "orientatie" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "orientatie" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'orientatie', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'rotation', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'rotation', 'precision': 0, 'type': 4}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "dieptePeil" IS NOT NULL THEN \r\nstring_to_array( "dieptePeil" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'dieptePeil', 'precision': 0, 'type': 6}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "diepteNauwkeurigheid" IS NOT NULL THEN \r\nstring_to_array( "diepteNauwkeurigheid" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nend', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'diepteNauwkeurigheid', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when diepteType IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "diepteType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'diepteType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "sewerWaterType" IS NOT NULL\r\nTHEN\r\nstring_to_array("SewerWaterType",\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND\r\n', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'sewerWaterType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when "isRisicovol" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "isRisicovol" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'isRisicovol', 'precision': 0, 'type': 1}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN warningType IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "warningType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'warningType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN utilityDeliveryType IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "utilityDeliveryType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'utilityDeliveryType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN nominalVoltage IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "nominalVoltage" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'nominalVoltage', 'precision': 0, 'type': 4}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN operatingVoltage IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "operatingVoltage" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'operatingVoltage', 'precision': 0, 'type': 4}, {'expression': 'Case WHEN isBovengrondsZichtbaar Is NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "isBovengrondsZichtbaar" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555, 'name': 'isBovengrondsZichtbaar', 'precision': 0, 'type': 1}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN containerType IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "containerType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'containerType', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "appurtenanceType" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("appurtenanceType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nWHEN "annotatieType" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("annotatieType",\'"\')[7]\r\nwhen "appurtenanceType" AND "annotatieType" IS NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "ElementType" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255455, 'name': 'Type', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN imkltype = \'appurtenance\' THEN \r\n\'ent_\' || \'Appurtenance\'\r\nWHEN imkltype =\'annotationlabel\' Then\r\n\'ent_\' || \'Annotatie\'\r\nWHEN imkltype=\'extraplan\' THEN\r\n\'ent_\' || \'ExtraPlan\'\r\nWHEN imkltype = \'electricitycable\' THEN \r\n\'ent_ElectricityCable\'\r\nWHEN imkltype =\'sewerpipe\' THEN\r\n\'ent_SewerPipe\'\r\nWHEN imkltype =\'waterpipe\' Then\r\n\'ent_\' || \'WaterPipe\'\r\nWHEN imkltype=\'maprequestzone\' THEN\r\n\'ent_MapRequestZone\'\r\nWHEN imkltype =\'duct\' THEN\r\n\'ent_Duct\'\r\nWHEN imkltype= \'annotation\' THEN\r\n\'ent_Annotatie\'\r\nelse\r\n\'ent_\' || "Header"\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'entity', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'replace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:\',\'\')', 'length': 255555555, 'name': 'hftUtilNet', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'replace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:\',\'\')', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'inNetwork_', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when theme IS NOT NULL THEN\n\'net_\' || string_to_array( "theme" ,\'"\')[7]\nELSE\nNULL\nEND\n', 'length': 2555555, 'name': 'nettype', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN\r\n\'ID_\' ||string_to_array("id" ,\':\')[2]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'gml_Id', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("id" ,\':\')[2]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'localId', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN unaName= \'Fluvius (ex-Infrax regio)\' AND "networkId" = \'UtilityNetwork:KLB-infrax-infrax:electra\'\r\nTHEN\r\nReplace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:KLB-infrax-infrax:electra\',\'KLB-infrax-infrax_electra\')\r\nWHEN unaName= \'Fluvius (ex-Infrax regio)\' AND "networkId" = \'UtilityNetwork:KLB-infrax-infrax:algemeen\'\r\nTHEN\r\nReplace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:KLB-infrax-infrax:algemeen\',\'KLB-infrax-infrax_algemeen\')\r\nElse\r\nsubstr((replace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:\',\'\')),1,strpos((replace("networkId", \'UtilityNetwork:\',\'\')),\':\')-1)\r\nEND', 'length': 25555, 'name': 'namespace', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE WHEN "validFrom" IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array("validFrom" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555555, 'name': 'validFrom', 'precision': 0, 'type': 16}, {'expression': '\'klb_\' || "unaName"', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'klb', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': '"UnazoneId"', 'length': 25555555, 'name': 'unaZoneId', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'Case when theme IS NOT NULL THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "theme" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'UtilityNet', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE when Header = \'Pole\' THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nend', 'length': 255555, 'name': 'dieptePeil(P)', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE when Header = \'Pole\' THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,\'"\')[2]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nend', 'length': 25557, 'name': 'diepteNauwkeurigheid(P)', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE When Imkltype = \'annotationlabel\' THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,\'"\')[7]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555555, 'name': 'dieptePeil(Ann)', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}, {'expression': 'CASE When Imkltype = \'annotationlabel\' THEN\r\nstring_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,\'"\')[2]\r\nELSE\r\nNULL\r\nEND', 'length': 2555555, 'name': 'diepteNauwkeurigheid(Ann)', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}], INPUT: 'C:/Users/joeri/Documents/GIS/IKML Mercator/ORDVV2001815 Zelzate (GVV)/pmkl.json|layername=featureCollection|geometrytype=Point', OUTPUT: 'memory:Bijgewerkt' }
Fout in evaluatie in expressie "CASE When Imkltype = 'annotationlabel' THEN 
string_to_array( "standaardDekking" ,'"')[7] 
ELSE 
NULL 
END": [] can only be used with map or array values, not 
Fout bij uitvoeren van Omzetting fase 1: Punten
Fout bij uitvoeren van Omzetting fase 1: Punten
Uitvoering mislukt na 0.48 seconden

Resultaatlagen laden
Algoritme 'KLIP Omzet' voltooid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I had a big of a facepalm moment***, I realized I could make my expression more simpler because I knew STDK would be NULL except in those situations. I had to make the expression more similar:
I could reuse these columns for other point shapefiles created in this process:

```
CASE when standaardDekking IS NOT NULL THEN
string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[7]
ELSE
NULL
end

CASE when standaardDekking IS NOT NULL THEN
string_to_array(  "standaardDekking"  ,'"')[3]
ELSE
NULL
end
```

Comment: Glad we could help you ;-)